# Los datos no se imprimen con el json_encode

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
include ("connex.php");


$sql = "Select item_parent.id_item_parent, item_parent.html_item_parent,
  item_parent.km_cambio_item_parent, item_parent.nombre
From parent_tipo left Join
  item_parent On item_parent.id_parent_tipo = parent_tipo.id_parent_tipo
Where parent_tipo.id_parent_tipo = 1 And item_parent.km_cambio_item_parent <=
 10000";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$total = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $fila ) {
         $total[] = $fila;
    }
    print json_encode(array("res"=>"ok" , "total"=>$total));

} else {
    print json_encode(array("res"=>"bad" , "msj"=>"No hay coincidencias"));
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Me hacen falta más datos para poder decirte cualquier caso...
¿Has probado a poner trazas para determinar por dónde entra la ejecución en el if? 
¿Has ejecutado la consulta directamente en base datos y comprobado que devuelve datos? 
¿Qué te imprime el script?

Comment: Debes poner algo más de información para que se te pueda ayudar a resolver tu problema, poniendo sólo el código sin ninguna explicación, ni traza de errores, ni comportamiento esperado, .. poco se podrá hacer

Comment: Estas seguro que en el **foreach** es correcto llamar **$conn->query**?

Answer (score 1):

Sustituye esto:

```
foreach($conn->query($sql) as $fila ) {
   $total[] = $fila;
}
```

Por esto:

```
while($result_row = $result->fetch_object()) {
   $total[] = $result_row;
}
```

Además, comprueba que la consulta esté realizada de forma correcta.